# Loading Data with shp2pgsql and "Syntax error at or near shp2pgsql"

Tags: shapefile, postgis-2.0

I want to import a shapefile using shp2pgsql function in the psql shell on Mac. I have created a spatial database (example_gis). By refering to this [guide](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg), having connected to this database, when I used:

```
example_gis=# shp2pgsql -s 4326 tl_2015_us_county.shp tl_2015_us_county postgres > tl_2015_us_county.sql;
```

An error was returned:

```
"ERROR:  syntax error at or near "shp2pgsql""
```

What is the possible reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this tool from command line, not from psql.

Comment: True. That really helps.